# Getting ClassNotFound Exception while executing shell script

Tags: java, shell, unix, jar

I want to write a shell script, which should call classes inside the jars. I am getting a `ClassNotFound Exception` when one jar's class file calling another jar's class file.

Here is what I've tried:

```
cd /home/appteam/encrypt/REPORT/CRYPTO4REPORT/
echo $1
echo $2
pwd

set JAVA_HOME = /App/jdk1.6.0_25/bin;

set path= /App/jdk1.6.0_25/bin;


java -classpath .:jars/log4j-1.2.8.jar:jars/xmlsec-1.4.2.jar:jars/CryptoUtils.jar:jars/bcprov-jdk15-146.jar:jars/commons-logging.jar:jars/Utils.jar:jars/Crypto.jar com.crypto.pki.PkiCrypto 1>> files/log/SuccessLog.log 2>>files/log/ErrorLog.log "ILI_RPT_TRV_07022013_001.enc" "crypto4decrypt.properties" DECRYPT
```

From the above code, I am calling com.crypto.pki.PkiCrypto class which is inside  Crypto.jar. Form the PriCrypto class calling FileUtil class which is inside Utils.jar.

I receive a `ClassNotFoundException` when PriCrypto class file uses the FileUtil class.

I got following Exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/common/utils/FileUtil
       at com.crypto.pki.PkiCrypto.processFile(PkiCrypto.java:75)
       at com.crypto.pki.PkiCrypto.main(PkiCrypto.java:31)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.common.utils.FileUtil
       at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
       at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
       at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
       ... 2 more
```

Comment: Please show the *complete* exception - currently you've given us no indication of what class can't be found.

Answer (score 0):

check Utils.jar is in the class path while running the program and also verify that utils.jar contains com.common.utils.FileUtil class